# rotating axis titles and adjusting scaling in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, graphics

[image: graphic] I made the following graphic in RStudio using ggplot2. Is there a way that I can rotate the axis title "Number of People" so it is horizontal instead of vertical? Also, is there a way I can adjust the spacing of the y-axis ticks so they are more uniform? The space from 0 to 10 is smaller than the rest of the spaces between ticks. If we were using the spacing from 0 to 10, then 40 would be slightly above 20.

```
ggplot(Project, aes(x = Year)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = SHL, color = "Sheltered Hispanic or Latino")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = UHL, color = "Unsheltered Hispanic or Latino")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red"))+
  labs(title = "Homelessness by Ethnicity",
       y = "Number of People", color = "Status",
       caption = "Source: 2022 AHAR: Part 1 - PIT Estimates of Homelessness in the U.S. \n Hispanic or Latino data only available since 2015.") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2015,2022, 2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 40, 5)) + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0)) +
  theme_classic()
```

I tried to correct the "Number of People" question with the axis.title.y line. It didn't work out, and I'm wondering if my request is even possible. For the spacing question, I don't know where to begin.

Comment: you don't have 0 in there you can make the yaxis go to 0 by using expand_limits(y=0), your y axis text should be horizontal with your code, may want to add a vjust to center it a la element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'll read up on that command.

Answer (score 1):

you should switch the order of theme functions, try this

```
ggplot(Project, aes(x = Year)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = SHL, color = "Sheltered Hispanic or Latino")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = UHL, color = "Unsheltered Hispanic or Latino")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red"))+
  labs(title = "Homelessness by Ethnicity",
       y = "Number of People", color = "Status",
       caption = "Source: 2022 AHAR: Part 1 - PIT Estimates of Homelessness in the U.S. \n Hispanic or Latino data only available since 2015.") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2015,2022, 2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 40, 5), limits = c(0, 45)) + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue with axis title move your `theme` adjustment after `theme_classic` otherwise it will be overwritten by the `theme_classic` defaults. For the issue with your axis set the `limits` to start at 0. Additionally I have set the exapnsion on the lower end to zero.

Using some fake random data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

Project <- data.frame(
  Year = 2015:2022,
  SHL = runif(8, 5, 45),
  UHL = runif(8, 5, 45)
)

ggplot(Project, aes(x = Year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = SHL, color = "Sheltered Hispanic or Latino")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = UHL, color = "Unsheltered Hispanic or Latino")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  labs(
    title = "Homelessness by Ethnicity",
    y = "Number of People", color = "Status",
    caption = "Source: 2022 AHAR: Part 1 - PIT Estimates of Homelessness in the U.S. \n Hispanic or Latino data only available since 2015."
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2015, 2022, 2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 40, 5), limits = c(0, NA), expand = c(0, 0, .05, 0)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation through *R for Data Science*, I learned that the title can be centered in a ggplot2 theme by placing the `theme()` line after the `theme_classic()` line. Also, the axis scalings can be adjusted by adding limits to the `scale_y_continuous()` (or `scaling_x_continuous()` for that matter) line. It does not appear that there is a way to adjust the rotation of the axis title.

```
ggplot(Project, aes(x = Year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = SHL, color = "Sheltered Hispanic or Latino")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = UHL, color = "Unsheltered Hispanic or Latino")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red")) +
  labs(title = "Homelessness by Ethnicity",
       y = "Number of People", color = "Status",
       caption = "Source: 2022 AHAR: Part 1 - PIT Estimates of Homelessness in the U.S. \n Hispanic or Latino data only available since 2015.") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2015,2022, 2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 40, 5), limits = c(0,45)) + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"))
```